# How to select a row with particular class name in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table as follows

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="start">Starting Point<input type="button" value="start the test" onclick="get_the_next()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>not the right class - skip me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="concept1">
        <td>get me if you can!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="concept2">
        <td>but not me, I'm not the next</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>not the right class - skip me</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to select row with class name "concept2". How can I do that in JQuery?

Comment: There is a good tutorial at [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)

Comment: I enjoyed this one: [jQuery Fundamentals](http://www.minihowtos.net/download/files/jQuery/jQuery_Fundamentals.pdf) by Rebecca Murphey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var row = $('.concept2');
});
```

To explain, the `jQuery(function($) { ... });` attaches the callback (ie the "function") to the *DOM Ready* event. This ensures your code only runs after the entire document had loaded.

The `$('.concept2')` uses jQuery's CSS style selectors. In this case, it is using the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

### Update

To answer your comment, check out the [manipulation category](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). An example might be

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('tr.concept2').html('<td>new data</td>');
});
```

I suggest you get very familiar with the [API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Phil@ Thank you for the quick response. If I have to update this row with table data say <td>new data</td>. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var rows = $('.concept2');
});
```

This will work on page ready event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr.concept2");
```

That ensures that only `tr`s named `concept2` will be selected, and not other elements. If there is only one `<tr class="concept2">`, use an ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use .each jquery method to do that..

```
 $("table").find("tr").each(function() { 

                $(this).find('td.start').text('hi'); 

                //if we want to append the text of the td's then we use 

                //$(this).find('td.concept2').append($('<div>HIHI</div>'));
             });
```

Hope This will helps you?
+1 If Helpfull